# The left adjoint to the forgetful functor $G\colon\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{C}\to\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ and Barr-Beck

Tags: category-theory, monads

Let $G\colon\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{C}\to\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ be the forgetful functor from $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces to $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces. I am trying to explicitly construct the left adjoint $F$ to $G$.

<strike>Any object $V\in\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ is an abelian group $A$ with an action of $\mathbb{R}$.
The 'obvious' way to extend this to a $\mathbb{C}$-action is to define $(x+iy)\cdot a=(x\cdot a)+ i\,(y\cdot a)$
which gives $A$ the structure of a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and write $F$ to mean the functor given by this construction.</strike>

<strike>It then seems obvious (which is always cause for alarm) that $GF=\mathrm{id}_{\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}}$ and reasonably believable (which means nothing really) that $FG\cong\mathrm{id}_{\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}}$ *but this seems far to nice to be true.*</strike>

In particular, this comes up as an exam question, where we are then asked to describe the explicit monad $GF$ on $\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ and the equivalence (from Barr-Beck) of $\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{C}\to\mathsf{Alg}_{GF}(\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R})$.

1. <strike>Is my construction of $F$ correct?</strike>
2. <strike>Are the facts about $GF$ and $FG$ I stated correct?</strike>
3. <strike>Assuming that some of the above is wrong</strike> **how can we show that every $G$-spit pair we can construct their coequaliser and show that it is preserved by $G$?**

**Edit:** For the third question, I know that $F$ being a left adjoint implies that it commutes with colimits, and thus that $$F\Big(\mathrm{coeq}\big(G(V)\rightrightarrows G(W)\big)\Big) = \mathrm{coeq}\big(FG(V)\rightrightarrows FG(W)\big)$$ which goes some of the way towards constructing the coequaliser in $\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{C}$ given the coequaliser in $\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$, but I haven't used the $G$-split property anywhere.

---

**Edit 2:** Thanks to the comments I'm pretty certain that $$F=(-\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})$$ is the left adjoint that we're looking for (and it is exact since $\mathbb{C}$ is a free $\mathbb{R}$-module and thus flat).
What I'm having trouble with now is showing that $G$ satisfies the conditions of the Barr-Beck theorem, in particular the fact that **every $G$-split pair has a coequaliser and it is preserved by $G$.**

---

**Edit 3:** Showing that $G$ preserves the coequaliser (assuming that it exists) follows from the fact that $G$ is exact: since adjoints are unique up to isomorphism, we know that $G\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C},-)$, but $\mathbb{C}$ is free and thus projective, and thus $G$ is exact.
Hence $G$ commutes with colimits.

So all that remains is to explicitly construct the coequaliser of $V\rightrightarrows W$ but I don't know where to begin.
**How can we use the fact that this pair is $G$-split?**

---

**Final (?) edit:** I think that the answer is actually quite trivial: we know that the coequaliser in $\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}$ *always* exists since $\mathsf{Vect}_\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\hbox{-}\mathsf{mod}$ has finite colimits (in fact it is bicomplete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to turn a real vector space into a complex one in general. Think, for example, about vector spaces of odd dimension. The even dimensional ones *can* be turned into complex ones  but in many ways, and there is no way to do it functorially.

This means that what you wrote does not define a functor (nor anything else, reallythe, as the "definition" does not work: you wrote "this gives the structureof a complex vector space", but it doesn't) so your two first questions have no answer.

I suggest that you try to find the adjoint before embarking in the third one or in any thing else!

Comment: I don't think I mentioned complete vector spaces? Or are you saying that the question as stated is wrong in some way?

Comment: This is a good example of why one should fear the word "obvious"...

Comment: The exam question asks us to 'explicitly describe a left adjoint $F$', but you're saying that there is no functoral way of constructing such an $F$, let alone describe it explicitly, yes?

Comment: I said what I wrote: that your attempt at defining a functor does not work: it does not define anything. It simply does not make sense. There *is* a left adjoint functor, though.

Comment: Is it simply the free $\mathbb{C}$-module on the set of basis vectors of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space then? This doesn't seem overly functorial though, since we have to pick a basis...

Comment: No, it is not: as you say, vector spaces do not come with a choice of basis, so you simply cannot make that functorial.

Comment: What you want is to "extend scalars".

Comment: $F=(-\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})$?